# Magnifying power of water-air surface

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics

If you look at an object through water it looks bigger/closer: I am trying to compute the magnifying power of the water-air interface and got stuck at some point. In particular I want to compute the ratio between the real and apparent depth of the object.

Here is my reasoning so far

[image]

the length of the object is given by

$$
\begin{cases}
d = (l+\Delta l_{\text{apparent}}) \cdot \tan(\theta_{air})\\
d = l \cdot \tan(\theta_{\text{air}}) + \Delta l_{\text{real}}\cdot \tan(\theta_{\text{water}})
\end{cases}
$$

equating the two I get

$$\Delta l_{\text{apparent}}\cdot \tan(\theta_{\text{air}}) = \Delta l_{\text{real}}\cdot \tan(\theta_{\text{water}})$$

therefore

$$
\frac{\Delta_{\text{apparent}}}{\Delta_{\text{real}}} = \frac{\tan(\theta_{\text{water}})}{\tan(\theta_{\text{air}})}
$$

and using Snell's law, assuming that the refractive index of water is $n\approx \frac{4}{3}$ I get

$$
\frac{\Delta_{\text{apparent}}}{\Delta_{\text{real}}} = \frac{4}{3}\frac{\cos(\theta_{\text{water}})}{\cos(\theta_{\text{air}})}
$$

Now I am stuck because I don't understand if this equation can be simplified further getting one number or the magnification depends on the parameters, therefore we don't get simply a number. Any idea?

Comment: Refraction on a plane interface isn't really magnification. Think about somebody on the shore, who sees the object shallower, but not displaced at all horizontally.

Comment: O probably I wasn't precise. Anyway I meant exactly that, i.e. the real vs apparent depth of the object.